# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to write a program for my C Programming class. The error in the title keeps popping up after I run the program with zero errors and warnings. Here's my code

```
/*
   Write a program that contains the function calories() that is to accept a long integer number total and the addresses of the integer variables pizza, chips, apples, and mustard.
   The passed long integer represents the total number of calories you are able to consume in this meal, and the function is to determine the 
   number of calories in slices of pizza, bags of chips, apples,
   and teaspoons of mustard in the passed value, writing these values directly into the respective variables declared in the calling function.

   This function will be called from the main program and when it returns to main, it will print out the values of variables pizza, chips, apples, and mustard.

   The calories in our favorite foods are in this order:
   pizza--385 calories each slice
   chips--170 calories each bag
   apple--80 calories each
   mustard--5 calories each tsp.
   For example, if I enter a total amount of calories of 1050, I can eat:
   2 slices pizza @ 770 calories (1050 - 770 = 280 calories remain)
   1 bag of chips @ 170 calories (280 - 170 = 110 calories remain)
   1 apple @ 80 calories (110 - 80 = 30 calories remain)
   6 tsp. mustard @ 30 calories
   */
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int calorie(int, int , int, int);

    int total, pizza, chips, apples, mustard, sum, sum1, sum2, sum3;

    pizza = 385;
    chips = 170;
    apples = 80;
    mustard = 5;

    printf("How many calories do you want to consume during your meal?");
    scanf("%d", total);

    total=calorie(pizza, chips, apples, mustard);


    printf("Pizza: %.2d", &pizza);
    printf("Chips: %.2d", &sum1);
    printf("Apples: %.2d", &sum2);
    printf("Mustard: %.2d", &sum3);

    return 0;

}

int calorie(pizza, chips, apples, mustard)
{
    int clfp, sum1, sum2, clfa, clfc, sum3, calorie;

    pizza = calorie/pizza;
    sum1 = calorie-pizza; /*calories left from pizza*/

    sum1 = clfp/chips;
    clfc = clfp-chips; /*calories left from chips*/

    sum2 = clfc/apples; /*calories life from apples*/
    clfa = clfc-apples ;

    sum3 = clfa/mustard;

    return pizza, sum1, sum2, sum3;
}
```

Comment: You can't do `return pizza, sum1, sum2, sum3;`, you can return only 1 value.

Comment: @Rohan: what happens there is that the compiler returns the value of `sum3` - the other stuff is the evaluation of the comma operator.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes, but not sure that is what OP intends to do.

Comment: @Rohan - I'm sure you're right that it's not what is intended. I thought you were saying that the compiler wouldn't permit it - I see now what you're saying.

Comment: `printf("Pizza: %.2d", &pizza);` - this is wrong. The format specifier says to print a number but you're passing a pointer.

Comment: @Gizmo: try using the compiler option `-Wall` which will point out many of the problems in the program.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what `&` does.

Answer (score 3):

1) Change

```
int calorie(int, int , int, int);
```

to

```
int calorie(int *, int *, int *, int *); // send pointers, so that you can update them in function call.
```

2) Change call

```
calorie(pizza, chips, apples, mustard);
```

to

```
calorie(&pizza, &chips, &apples, &mustard); // send address of variables.
```

3) Change return

```
return pizza, sum1, sum2, sum3;
```

to

```
return 0; // to indicate success.
```

4) Change

```
printf("Pizza: %.2d", &pizza);
printf("Chips: %.2d", &sum1);
printf("Apples: %.2d", &sum2);
printf("Mustard: %.2d", &sum3);
```

to

```
printf("Pizza: %.2d", pizza);
printf("Chips: %.2d", sum1);
printf("Apples: %.2d", sum2);
printf("Mustard: %.2d", sum3);
```

5) Change

```
scanf("%d", total);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &total);
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d", total);` should be `scanf("%d", &total);`

Also it doesn't make much sense to read in a value for `total` in the `scanf()` call only to completely ignore it and overwrite the value by calling:

```
total=calorie(pizza, chips, apples, mustard);
```

Another problem is that you use the variable `calorie` without ever initializing it in the `calorie()` function:

```
pizza = calorie/pizza;
//       ^^^^^ uninitialized
```

I'm also surprised that your `calorie()` function definition even compiles since none of the identifiers within the parens are types. But I find that it compiles for me, so what do I know (I guess it's implicit `int` rearing its ugly head)?

```
int calorie(pizza, chips, apples, mustard)  // <- what?
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all thoses suggestions, here is a fixed version of the code, for your reference:

```
/*
   Write a program that contains the function calories() that is to accept
   a long integer number total and the addresses of the integer variables 
   pizza, chips, apples, and mustard.

   The passed long integer represents the total number of calories you are 
   able to consume in this meal, and the function is to determine the number 
   of calories in slices of pizza, bags of chips, apples, and teaspoons of 
   mustard in the passed value, writing these values directly into the 
   respective variables declared in the calling function.

   This function will be called from the main program and when it returns to 
   main, it will print out the values of variables pizza, chips, apples, and 
   mustard.

   The calories in our favorite foods are in this order:
   pizza--385 calories each slice
   chips--170 calories each bag
   apple--80 calories each
   mustard--5 calories each tsp.
   For example, if I enter a total amount of calories of 1050, I can eat:
   2 slices pizza @ 770 calories (1050 - 770 = 280 calories remain)
   1 bag of chips @ 170 calories (280 - 170 = 110 calories remain)
   1 apple @ 80 calories (110 - 80 = 30 calories remain)
   6 tsp. mustard @ 30 calories
   */

#include <stdio.h>

void calorie(long, int *, int *, int *, int *);

int main()
{
    long total;
    int pizza, chips, apples, mustard;

    printf("How many calories do you want to consume during your meal? ");
    scanf("%ld", &total);

    calorie(total, &pizza, &chips, &apples, &mustard);

    printf("Pizza:   %2d\n", pizza);
    printf("Chips:   %2d\n", chips);
    printf("Apples:  %2d\n", apples);
    printf("Mustard: %2d\n", mustard);

    return 0;

}

void calorie(long total, int *pizza, int *chips, int *apples, int *mustard)
{
    const int per_pizza = 385;
    const int per_chips = 170;
    const int per_apples = 80;
    const int per_mustard = 5;

    *pizza = total / per_pizza;
    total -= *pizza * per_pizza;

    *chips = total / per_chips;
    total -= *chips * per_chips;

    *apples = total / per_apples;
    total -= *apples * per_apples;

    *mustard = total / per_mustard;
    total -= *mustard * per_mustard;
}
```